# How can we go from a 4-dimensional representation of $SO(4)$ to the 3-dimensional one of its proper subgroup $SO(3)$?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

In Walter Greiner's book, "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics", when discussing infinitesimal tranformations:

$$x^{\prime\nu}=a^{\nu}{}_{\mu}x^{\mu},$$

where the $a^{\nu}{}_{\mu}$ is are infinitesimal elements of $SO(4)$:

$$a^{\nu}{}_{\mu}=\delta^{\nu}{}_{\mu}+\epsilon^{\nu}{}_{\mu}.$$

He establishes the group generators as follows :

$$\sum_{\sigma,\rho} \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{\sigma}{}_{\rho} (\hat I^{\nu}{}_{\mu})^{\sigma\rho} = \epsilon^{\nu}{}_{\mu},$$

or when lowering the index $\nu$:

$$\sum_{\sigma,\rho} \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{\sigma}{}_{\rho} (\hat I_{\tau}{}_{\mu})^{\sigma\rho} = \epsilon_{\tau}{}_{\mu},$$

and to determine the matrix representation of the generators, he uses the ansatz :
$$(\hat I_{\mu}{}_{\nu})^{\sigma\rho} = g^{\sigma}{}_{\mu}g^{\rho}{}_{\nu} - g^{\sigma}{}_{\nu}g^{\rho}{}_{\mu},$$

After establishing the commutations relations between generators, he introduces six linearly independent combinations :
$$\hat I^{i(+)} = \frac{1}{2} (\hat I^{kl} + \hat I^{i0})$$
$$\hat I^{i(-)} = \frac{1}{2} (\hat I^{kl} - \hat I^{i0})$$

with $i,k,l$ are cylic permutations of $1,2,3$. At this point he claims that doing so, we have constructed two $3 \times 3$ matrices, $\hat I^{i(\pm)}$, from the $4 \times 4$ matrix $\hat I^{\sigma\rho}$.

1. How so ? Can we write out explicitly these new matrices, or do we have to make certain transformations? Because my best guess so far has been that since these two new matrices commute, we can find a way to diagonalize them and then extract the $3 \times 3$ matrices he's talking about.
2. What is the actual procedure to follow to move from $SO(4)$ to its subgroup $SO(3)$ through these new matrices he introduced?

Comment: I'm just starting dabbling in group theory. I do however have an idea about how these transformations lead to angular momentum generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite what you say. Yes ${\rm SO}(4)$ has an obvious collection of ${\rm SO}(3)$ subgroups where one rotates in 3-dimensional subspaces of of the 4-dimensional space---  but Greiner's ${\rm SO}(3)$'s  are none of these. Further,  his $I_i^{(\pm)}$ are still 4-by-4 matrices. It is just that one can find 3-by-3 matrices that have the same commutation representations as as these 4-by-4 matrices.

What is true is that locally (i.e in the Lie algebra)  ${\rm SO}(4)\simeq {\rm SU}(2) \times {\rm SU}(2) $ and each of the ${\rm SU}(2)$'s is locally isomorphic to ${\rm SO}(3)$ which has a 3-dimensional representation.

The isomorphism ${\rm SO}(4)\simeq {\rm SU}(2) \times {\rm SU}(2) $ comes about because the group manifold of $ {\rm SU}(2) $ is the three-sphere $S^3$, whose isometry  group is naturally ${\rm SO}(4)$. Now the group of isometries of any Lie group $G$ is $G\times G/Z$ where $Z$ is the centre (the set of elements that commutes with everything in $G$). Under an element  $(g_L,g_R)\in G\times G$ we have that  $g\mapsto g_L g (g_R)^{-1}$ and if $g_L=g_R \in Z$ this map does nothing to $g$;  hence the need to quotient out the $Z$.  The resulting ${\rm SU}(2)$ actions on $S^3$ induced by the generators ${\bf I}^{(+)}$ and ${\bf I}^{(-)}$ are not exactly easy to visulize.

Given an ${\rm SO}(4)$ rotation $\hat O$ it is not easy to determine the $a_{ij}$  in  $\hat O= \exp\{\sum_{ij} a_{ij}I^{ij}\}$ but  this is the necessary  first step in factoring the matrix as  as
$$
\hat O= \exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^3 a^{(+)} _i I_i^{(+)}\right\} \exp\left\{\sum_{j=1}^3 a^{(-)}_j I_j^{(+)}\right\}.
$$
If you do succeed in this factorization, you must  replace each factor by its 3-by-3 matrix representative in the 3-vector representation of ${\rm SU}(2)$. Each of the factors acts on its *own* 3-dimensional space, so the  ordinary matrix product of the commuting 4-by-4 matrices must be  replaced by the *tensor  product* of the3-by-3  matrices. One ends   up with 9-by-9 matrices acting on the 9-dimensional tensor product space of the two 3-dimensional representation spaces.

So, bottom line: Given any  4-by-4 matrix in ${\rm SO}(4)$ one can produce *pairs* of  ${\rm SO}(3)$ matrices, but only rather special  ${\rm SO}(4)$ matrices produce a single ${\rm SO}(3)$ matrix, and constructing these pairs from the original 4-by-4 matrices is not straightforward.  I do not know any simple recipe.

Comment: That does actually bring a lot more sense to it, even though I'm still shaky on group theory.
How it was handled in the book threw me off; I was looking for a straightforward step that I missed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know exactly what Greiner wants to say, it seems to be rather obvious that he wants to construct the Lie-algebra of the Lorentz-group (or as it is mentioned in the post: of SO(4)) starting from the 4-vector representation.

SO(4) and the Lorentz-group are not the same groups since SO(4) is based on the Euklidean metric whereas the Lorentz-group is based on the Minkowski-metric and due to that there will be differences in the contruction of the Lie-algebras of both groups.
Actually, I only know well how to construct the Lie-algebra of the Lorentz-group, so I will move on with this, but I assume that for the SO(4) it is very similar.

For the Lorentz-group the (Lie-algebra)-elements (so may be for SO(4) the complex $i$ is not necessary, to be checked)

$$\hat I^{i(+)} = \frac{1}{2}(\hat I^{kl} + i \hat I^{i0}) \quad \text{and} \quad \hat I^{i(-)} = \frac{1}{2}(\hat I^{kl} - i \hat I^{i0})$$

are defined which then fulfill the following commutation relations (Lorentz-group and SO(4)):

$$[\hat I^{i \pm}, \hat I^{k \pm}] = \epsilon_{ikl} \hat I^{l \pm} \quad \text{and} \quad [\hat I^{i -}, \hat I^{k +}] =0  $$

Of course, in this construction of the Lie-algebra the used matrices remain $4\times 4$, but the now evident question from the representation theory's point of view is: Which matrices fulfill the found algebra, or more precisely formulated: what are the representations of the found Lie-algebra ?

A look on the commutation relations show that the found Lie-algebra is actually a direct sum of two and identical Lie-algebras: The Lie-algebra of SO(3) or SU(2) (as both groups have the same Lie-algebra) if real linear combinations are considered or the Lie-algebra of SL(2,C) if a complex Lie-algebra is considered.

Therefore, the commutation relations can be very well fulfilled by $3\times 3$ matrices (which can be obtained from the infinitesimal development of group elements of SO(3), i.e. rotations). And I guess this is what Greiner meant in his book. For completeness it has to be added that the commutation relations can be fulfilled by any $(2j+1)\cdot (2j'+1)$ dim.-matrices where $j,j'=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},\ldots $. In this post we have discussed the case $j,j'=\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}$  (4-dim matrices)   and the $j=1,j'=0$ (3-dim matrices).

To be clear: the found Lie-algebra is the Lie-algebra of the group $SO(3)\times SO(3)$  (which actually indicates that $SO(4)/\{Id,-Id\}\cong SO(3)\times SO(3)$) if real combinations of Lie-algebra elements are used, whereas if complex linear combinations are used it is the group $SL(2,C) \times SL(2,C)$.
As long as only SO(4) is considered the $i$ in the recast of the Lie-algebra elements is not necessary the construction of SO(4) representations is rather easy.
However, in case of the Lie-algebra of the proper Lorentz-group (where the $i$ in the definition of the $\hat I^{i \pm}$ is necessary), the correct construction of the Lorentz-group representations is an intricate chapter of representation theory which is out of scope here.

In order to return from SO(4) to SO(3), just remove the $\hat I^{0}$ of the definition of the $\hat I^{i \pm}$, the $\hat I^{kl}$ alone already fulfill the Lie-algebra of SO(3).